# Using the random() function in p5.js

Tags: javascript, random, processing, p5.js

I am trying to create a code where a smiley face is drawn at random on-screen and in a random colour which should loop but I can't figure out how best to use the random() function to accomplish this. Can anyone give me some pointers! I have tried using variables (var inside the draw function to call function smileyFace but no luck!

CODE:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(220);
  smileyFace(random(0, 400), random(0, 400));
}

function draw() {

}

function smileyFace(x, y) {
  fill(250);
  ellipse(x, y, 60, 60);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(x - 10, y - 10, 10, 10);
  ellipse(x + 10, y - 10, 10, 10);
  arc(x, y + 5, 30, 25, 0, PI, CHORD);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are errors reported ? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: A smiley face is drawn and placed at a random point on the screen but it is (A.) Not repeating the smiley face and placing it on screen at random and (B.) Not changing colour each time a smiley face is placed. There is no errors as of yet as I can not figure out how to accomplish the task!

Comment: @ApexSnake Are you expecting multiple smiley faces to be drawn on the one canvas?

Comment: Shouldn't the function call to draw the face be in the `draw()` function? That's the function that p5 will call over and over again on each frame. (You'll also want to call `background()` there to clear the canvas.)

Comment: @NickParsons yes multiple smiley faces drawn on one canvas random colours (r,g,b) and placed at random on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] multiple smiley faces drawn on one canvas random colours (r,g,b) and placed at random on screen.

Just move the call `smileyFace` to the `draw` function and create a random color by

```js
c = color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
```

See the example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    background(220);
}

function draw() {
    c = color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
    smileyFace(random(0, 400), random(0, 400), c);
}

function smileyFace(x, y, c) {
    fill(c);
    ellipse(x, y, 60, 60);
    fill(255);
    ellipse(x - 10, y - 10, 10, 10);
    ellipse(x + 10, y - 10, 10, 10);
    arc(x, y + 5, 30, 25, 0, PI, CHORD);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `draw()` function in p5 executes multiple times, and so, if you wish to draw multtiple smiley faces you can place your `smileyFace()` method in the `draw()` method.

To get random colours you can pass a `color` object to the `fill(color)` method. To get the color, you can use the `color()` method, which accepts three values. The values are `r` (red), `g` (green), and `b` (blue) and need to be between 0-255. So, to get a random colour you can use `random(0, 255)` to get random values for each colour component (r, g & b):

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(220);
}

function draw() {
  smileyFace(random(0, 400), random(0, 400));
}

function smileyFace(x, y) {
  fill(getRandomColour());
  ellipse(x, y, 60, 60);
  
  fill(getRandomColour());
  ellipse(x - 10, y - 10, 10, 10);
  ellipse(x + 10, y - 10, 10, 10);
  arc(x, y + 5, 30, 25, 0, PI, CHORD);
}

function getRandomColour() {
  const r = random(0, 255);
  const g = random(0, 255);
  const b = random(0, 255);
  return color(r, g, b);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Nick this is perfect, I didn't even think of creating another function for creating the colours